# Realmlist - IP works but domain doesn't

Tags: docker, azerothcore

I'm struggling to get my AzerothCore Docker instance to allow logins via the internet when using a domain instead of an IP address. My ISP only offers dynamic IPs so I'm using dynu for simplicity.

If Realmlist set to domain in `acore_auth.realmlist` I can connect over LAN but external connections get stuck at realm select screen. However if I change the realmlist to just my external IP it works for both so doesn't look like a firewall issue.

The domain is working with webserver hosted on the same machine so that can't be the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly the reason why this fixed it, but I tweaked some of my pfSense settings for DNS resolution (removing my domain from the overrides) to get it going. Hopefully this might be useful to someone else!